# scriptaculous, prototype problem

Tags: javascript, windows, jsp

The code mentioned below works fine locally,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/scriptaculous.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    new Ajax.Autocompleter("empName","empNameOptions","empAutoComplete.jsp", {
        afterUpdateElement : getSelectionId,indicator: 'indicator1'
    });

    function getSelectionId(text, li) {
        $('empIdTT').value=li.id;
    }
}
</script>
```

BUT when I call the code from server (windows 2008), the .js apparently does not load at all, 
but when assign a new url for js the code works normal.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.someSite/lib/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.someSite/src/scriptaculous.js"></script>
```

what happen to the server? is there any configuration I must do it?

Note: I use tomcat and JSP technique
Please help

Comment: this might be issue of caching JS file. Try to reload the page after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Where is the file with the script tags located?

Answer (score 0):

In code snippet #1 the `src` is *relative*. Turn these to absolute paths and you're good (i.e. write `src="/lib/prototype.js"`).

Note: you're using prototype, so instead of assigning an anonymous function to `window.onload`, do:

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    // insert code here
});
```

This will allow for multiple functions running, when the DOM has been set up.

Comment: Thank u all for quick response. As I said the code works fine locally in the server itself, but when I run the code from client pc I got an error: Exception thrown and not caught, scriptaculous.js. Object doesn't support this property or method.
Please let me say that I put the code in other server and it works fine with NO error.